# How to extract interval/range of rows from compressed file?

Tags: linux, zcat

How do I return interval of rows from 100mil rows *.gz file?

Let's say I need 5 mil rows starting from 15mil up to 20mil?

is this the best performing option?

```
zcat myfile.gz|head -20000000|tail -500
real    0m43.106s
user    0m43.154s
sys     0m9.259s
```

Comment: or `zcat file | awk 'NR>14999999 && NR < 2000001{if (NR > 20000001) exit}' > outfile` might be a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfectly reasonable option; since you don't know how long a line will be, you basically have to decompress and iterate the lines to figure out where the line separators are. All three tools are fairly heavily optimized, so I/O and decompression time will likely dominate regardless.

In theory, rolling your own solution that combines all three tools in a single executable might save a little (by reducing the costs of IPC a bit), but the savings would likely be negligible.